# Do u know any good wordpress plugings for email alerts that has filters over the email types u want to recive

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, email-notifications

I m building a websit for a custommer on wordpress, and he wants a page with functions similar to [this one](https://travaillerensante.com/alerte-emplois/), where you may choose categories and receive alerts based on ur choice after receiving first an email to validate the address u gave.

I tried wp job manager, job alert, gravity forms, and formidable forms, and i was not abele to find this function, did i miss what i m looking for? do u have any good pluging that can help? or a solution with almost no coding?

PS: is it possible with contact form 7

Comment: You are free to use  any form, but this specific feature cannot be readily found in the Forms; instead, you must create it through customization.

Comment: Please note that "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*" Ref: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

After much time spend exploring the internet i found somthing call addons, so i used contact form 7 and [the following](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-addons-for-contact-form-7/)  to hidde and show checkboxes i don t want, goodluck!

Comment: Indeed, the addon will assist in minimizing the need for customization, yet you will still need to tailor it to suit your specific use cases. For further information on Contact Form 7 hooks and filters, you can refer to the following doc: https://contactform7.com/docs/